# BTRFS - Revert to snapshot

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

I have disk with btrfs file system which is mounted on root directory.

```
$ sudo btrfs subvol show  /media/qkiz/Corsair/
/media/qkiz/Corsair is btrfs root
```

On this this root is a snapshot.

```
$ sudo btrfs subvol show  /media/qkiz/Corsair/snapshot/
/media/mkukielka/Corsair/snapshot
    Name:           snapshot
    uuid:           94d5d0fa-aaf4-d84c-b716-d5121accf7a0
    Parent uuid:        -
    Creation time:      2015-12-02 13:31:18
    Object ID:      258
    Generation (Gen):   23
    Gen at creation:    23
    Parent:         5
    Top Level:      5
    Flags:          -
    Snapshot(s):
```

I make changes on root file system and now I want to back to snapshot. If I change default subvolume:

```
$ sudo btrfs subvol set-default 258 /media/qkiz/Corsair/
```

I can see state from snapshot but disk space is still used by root directory. How to delete root directory and use snapshot as root??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your life easier, I would recommend that the root btrfs subvolume (id=5) is only used to manage other subvolumes and snapshots. Don't store
a lot of data on the root subvolume and don't reference it in scripts etc.
This will make it a lot easier for you to make snapshots, do roll-backs etc.

For example, in fstab:

```
# Root of btrfs volume. Used for volume management.
# Do not reference /mnt/root-XYZ/ in scripts or software.
LABEL=XYZ /mnt/root-XYZ btrfs noauto,subvolid=5

# Software using data on this subvolume should reference this path:
#     /media/qkiz/Corsair/...
# and NOT /mnt/root-XYZ/corsair/...
#
LABEL=XYZ /media/qkiz/Corsair btrfs noauto,subvol=corsair
```

(you would change XYZ to your actual btrfs label)

Do put this into effect, you could create a snapshot of your root subvolume, and call it corsair. Probably also make a read-only snapshot of corsair, for backup purposes. Then delete files from the root subvolume. For example:

```
umount /mnt/qkiz/Corsair
mount /mnt/root-XYZ
cd /mnt/root-XYZ
btrfs subvol snap . corsair
btrfs subvol snap -r corsair corsair-YYMMDD
```

Check that corsair-YYMMDD/ contains your important data, then delete the data from your root subvolume:

```
rm -rf ./datafiles....
```

Finally, mount your new subvolume:

```
mount /mnt/qkiz/Corsair
```

You could make your 'corsair' subvolume the *default* subvolume if you wanted, but that is not strictly necessary. It could be useful if this is a portable drive and you move it to another machine with a different fstab. In that way, the *corsair* subvolume would be mounted by default, and not the root subvolume.